# How to Implement YouTube Direct Lite in Android 7

Tags: android, youtube

I discovered YouTube Direct Lite (Android/Java) on GitHub (https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android) as a good example of how to allow users to upload a video to your YouTube playlist. I've got it to work successfully in debug and release apk mode on Android 5.1.1 on Nexus 4 and Android 4.2.2. on Galaxy Tab 7. However, I get a "Connection to Play Services failed" message on installing to Android 7.0 on LG4. "Unfortunately, I-Witness (renamed app) Uploader has stopped" is the message before the app crashes, when I select my log-in account.

On initially importing the code from git, Android Studio 3.01 showed some outdated libraries, which I updated, and found a cure for a httprequest/httpclient error caused by one of said outdated libs. The biggest issues revolved around 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth' and 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus' which were at 7.8 in the original example.

Android Studio recommended update to the current 11.8 but when I did many 'red underlines of death' showed up in the code and so I was successful using 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.0' and com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0.

Specifically, 11.8 causes a conflict with the below external libraries related to firebase, which I don't understand since firebase is not implemented in the project:

```
google.firebase:firebase-analytics-9.00
google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl-9.00
google.firebase:firebase-common-9.00
google.firebase:firebase-core-9.00
google.firebase:firebase-iid-9.00
```

The problem seems to revolve around authenticating but where to debug for the specific Android version?

Here's my app level build.gradle if anyone might be familiar with YouTube direct Lite and can make a suggestion to resolve installation on Android 7:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abengnews.iwitness"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev120-1.19.0'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:+'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:+'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thanks for any help.

P.S. It turns out the issue is related to `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />` in the  AndroidManifest.xml that was changed in Android 6.1>. I stumbled upon it while fiddling with the app's settings on the phone. "Contacts" was the only option listed under "Permissions" and when I enabled access to Contacts, the app functioned as expected.

Now I need to discover how to effect the permission programatically

Comment: Updated 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0' and Gradle sync has updated the firebase libraries accordngly but the problem of the crash remains. (Don't know why Gradle did not update the firebase libs previously.)

Comment: Hi, is that lib(YT direct lite) still support for Android? Or is you app work in Android 10 ?

Comment: The app development has been discontinued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message about the failure to connect to Play Services and the subsequent crash are related to the fact that `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />` in the AndroidManifest.xml, requires explicit granting of permission by the user since Android 6.1.

The following bits of code found in Android's example runtime permissions found [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions) have resolved the issues (although the app crashed on the first run after installation but not subsequently).

When the main activity content view loads:

```
        // Verify that all required contact permissions have been granted.
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Contacts permissions have not been granted.
            Log.i(TAG, "Contact permissions has NOT been granted. Requesting permissions.");
            requestContactsPermissions();
        }
```

And then requesting and setting permissions:

```
// permissions
/**
 * Id to identify a contacts permission request.
 */
private static final int REQUEST_CONTACTS = 1;

/**
 * Permissions required to read and write contacts. Used by the .
 */
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_CONTACT = {Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS,
};

/**
 * Requests the Contacts permissions.
 * If the permission has been denied previously, a SnackBar will prompt the user to grant the
 * permission, otherwise it is requested directly.
 */
private void requestContactsPermissions() {
    // BEGIN_INCLUDE(contacts_permission_request)
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)
            ) {

        // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
        // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
        // For example, if the request has been denied previously.
        Log.i(TAG,
                "Displaying contacts permission rationale to provide additional context.");

        // Display a SnackBar with an explanation and a button to trigger the request.
        Snackbar.make(mLayout, R.string.permission_contacts_rationale,
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        ActivityCompat
                                .requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS_CONTACT,
                                        REQUEST_CONTACTS);
                    }
                })
                .show();
    } else {
        // Contact permissions have not been granted yet. Request them directly.
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_CONTACT, REQUEST_CONTACTS);
    }
    // END_INCLUDE(contacts_permission_request)
}
/**
 * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
 */
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACTS) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received response for contact permissions request.");

        // We have requested multiple permissions for contacts, so all of them need to be
        // checked.
        if (PermissionUtil.verifyPermissions(grantResults)) {
            // All required permissions have been granted, display contacts fragment.
            Snackbar.make(mLayout, R.string.permision_available_contacts,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Contacts permissions were NOT granted.");
            Snackbar.make(mLayout, R.string.permissions_not_granted,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    } else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

I'm sure there's some redundant code that can be cleaned up, since I don't have any buttons to click to request permissions.